# Laravel doesn't remember me after GoogleOAuth redirect

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-oauth

My application is meant to interact with the user's google calendar. So I set up all the GoogleOAuth stuff in the *Google APIs Console* and in laravel with the `google/apiclient` package via composer.

**GoogleCalendarApi.php**

```
public function __construct($redirectUri, $tokens = [], $state = '')
{
    $this->client = new \Google_Client();
    $this->client->setAuthConfig([
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    ]);
    $this->client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $this->client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
    $this->client->setAccessType('offline');

    if (! empty($tokens) && ! isset($tokens['error'])) {
        $this->client->setAccessToken($tokens);
    }
    if (! empty($state)) {
        $this->client->setState($state);
    }

    $this->calendar = new \Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
}
```

The `$redirectUri` is an internal url that's supposed to get the code and save it for the user to access the Calendar API when necessary.

**GoogleCalendarApiController.php**

```
public function oAuthRedirectTarget(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->get('code');
    $user = Auth::user();
    $instance = GoogleCalendarApi::getInstanceForUser($user);
    $tokens = $instance->client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);

    $user->setMeta('google_calendar_api_tokens', json_encode($tokens));

    return redirect(route('account.user'));
}
```

But the `oAuthRedirectTarget` function is only executed when I do not protect it with the `auth` guard, because as soon as the GoogleOAuth process redirects me to my application I am logged out.
Since I need the current user (which I don't have access to in a `guest` route) to save the tokens for them, I created a custom Guard that authenticates the user based on a temporary *remember_token*-like string. That did actually work and the tokens were saved to the current user, but since the route behind this line `return redirect(route('account.user'));` is protected by the default `auth` guard, I get redirected to the login screen.

I tried adding a wrapper around the OAuth url created with the package and using the internal `redirect` function to get there, and saving the session before redirecting, and even logging the user in manually again with the "remember" option set to true, but I keep getting logged out on return from Google.

**GoogleCalenderApiController.php**

```
public function oAuthCodeUrlWrapper(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $url = GoogleCalendarApi::getUserOAuthCodeUrl($user);

    $request->session()->save(); # doesn't help
    Auth::login($user, true); # doesn't help either
    return redirect($url);
}
```

I tried setting the `SESSION_DRIVER` to `cookie` instead of `file`, but that gave me a `Bad Gateway` error first (maybe a VM hiccup) and after some more fiddling I forgot, I was back to just being logged out.

So, all that forms the question:
How do I retain the current user's session after redirecting away to GoogleOAuth and coming back from there?

Comment: Since this was an old client's project I don't have access to it anymore.

Maybe it could have worked if I just set a Cookie with the UserId manually and would have used that to log the user in again. So not relying on the SESSION_DRIVER.